# Change a field property in SNOW

Tags: servicenow

I'm trying to change a field's default property in SNOW. Here in incidents we've a field **Assigned to** and it accepts some default values. But instead of that I want it to accept any values (Integer, String, Special characters etc). In my SNOW Form lay out tried the below.

Created a new String field, Named it as *Assigned to* Label and name as *assigned_to* and saved it and it ended up as shown below.

[image]

and when I added some random text in this field, it gave me the below error.
[image]

please let me know on how can I change this field to accept any string as Input.

Thanks

Comment: Since the `assigned_to` field is a *Reference* field pointing to the *User [sys_user]* table, it will only accept a reference to a User record and not random values. What is your end goal for this change? Maybe there is another way.

Answer (score 0):

You are referencing the `sys_user` table on the form field **Assigned to**. You need to provide the value for the **Assigned to** field the `sys_id` from the User record.

Providing it with any text will result in an invalid reference since it is looking for the unique `sys_id` on the user table.